# *How to solve uncontrolled set entered as constant?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know how to deal with error 149 in GAMS
here is the GAMS code

''' Sets
Customers / C1*C20 /
Orders / O1*O20 /
Weeks / W1*W4 /
Days / D1*D6 /
Products / P1*P20 /;

Parameters
OrderReceivingDate(Orders)
Deadline(Orders)
ProductionCapacityPerDay
WarehouseCapacityPerMonth
OrderQuantity(Orders, Products);

Variables
ProductionQuantity(Orders, Days, Products)
Lateness(Orders)
;

Positive Variable ProductionQuantity
TotalLateness;

Equations
DeadlineConstraint(Orders)
ProductionCapacityConstraint(Days)
WarehouseConstraint(Orders, Weeks)
FlowOfProductionConstraint(Orders, Days, Weeks)
LeadTimeConstraint(Orders, Days)
CustomerOrderFulfillmentConstraint(Orders, Products)
EarlyProductionAcceptedConstraint(Orders, Products)
LateProductionNotAcceptedConstraint(Orders, Products)
InventoryBalanceConstraint(Orders, Days, Products);

- Objective function
  Equation ObjectiveFunction;
  ObjectiveFunction..TotalLateness =e=sum(Orders, Lateness(Orders));
- Deadline Constraint
  DeadlineConstraint(Orders).. sum(Days, ProductionQuantity(Orders, Days, Products) ) =l= Deadline(Orders) + OrderReceivingDate(Orders) - 1;'''

here is the error
**DeadlineConstraint(Orders).. sum(Days, ProductionQuantity(Orders, Days, Products) ) =l= Deadline(Orders) + OrderReceivingDate(Orders) - 1;
****                                                                                  $149
**** 149  Uncontrolled set entered as constant**